# Select a group of lines in regex that are under a heading line

Tags: python, regex

Here's my problem. I am creating a parser for a movie-type script (not a computer script, but a screenplay), and I need to select all of the lines underneath a certain scene heading. Here's an example script from Shakespeare's *Hamlet*.

```
#Scene 1#
Bernardo: Who's there?
Francisco: Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.

#Scene 2#
Horatio: Tis now struck twelve; get thee to bed, Francisco.
Marcellus: Peace, break thee off; look, where it comes again!
```

I need a way to select everything between "#Scene 1#" and '#Scene 2#'. Bernardo and Francisco should match, but Horatio and Marcellus should not.

I've tried using lookahead and lookbehind, but apparently they don't work across multiple lines.

```
/(?<=#Scene 1#)(.*)(?=#Scene 2#)/gim
```

If it's important, I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe you just need to filter your lines with `startswith`?

Comment: `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` [will solve matching across lines](https://regex101.com/r/b59IPc/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex works perfectly fine. Just remember to use `re.DOTALL` flag

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=#Scene 1#)(.*)#Scene 2#', text, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
"\nBernardo: Who's there?\nFrancisco: Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of [this regex here](https://regex101.com/r/rYIzDB/1).

```
import re

data = """
#Scene 1#
Bernardo: Who's there?
Francisco: Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.

#Scene 2#
Horatio: Tis now struck twelve; get thee to bed, Francisco.
Marcellus: Peace, break thee off; look, where it comes again!
"""

print(re.findall(r'(?:#Scene 1#)\s*(.*?)\s*(?:#Scene 2#)', data, flags=re.DOTALL)[0])
```

Prints:

```
Bernardo: Who's there?
Francisco: Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.
```